# iOS app/ opencart webview

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, phonegap, itunes-store

I have a website based on opencart. I'm planning now to use the main features (listing, check out ... etc) from the webview. And integrate it with native ios code for (push notification, deeplinking, side menu, tabs bar for settings, search by using scan barcode .. etc.).

Also I will use some feature to be run on webview using [javascript bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/ObjCFromJavaScript.html)

My Question, does apple accept like this app? or it would be rejected ?

Answer (score 3):

Apple won't reject your app, if you are using JavaScript bridge with WKWebView. 
Go through the Apple app store review guidelines for better understanding : [https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements](http://%22Appstore%20guidelines%22)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will share my experience here if I got acceptance. :)

Comment: I have try to do that, that was great and easy to manage my mobile app.

Comment: @DeveloperSofar was your app accepted by Apple? Would you mind linking it here so we can check it out ;P